# jquery weird behavior of page refresh when i replace content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I have a site with an flash player.

This codes servers me the flash player stored in player_codes.php:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="songs_related/flashmp3player/swfobject.js" ></script>
<!-- Div that contains player. -->
<div id="player">
    <h1>No flash player!</h1>
    <p>It looks like you don't have flash player installed. <a href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" >Click here</a> to go to Macromedia download page.</p>
</div>

<!-- Script that embeds player. -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var so = new SWFObject("songs_related/flashmp3player/flashmp3player.swf", "player", "290", "247", "9"); // Location of swf file. You can change player width and height here (using pixels or percents).
    so.addParam("quality", "high");
    so.addVariable("content_path","songs_related/uploads"); // Location of a folder with mp3 files (relative to php script).
    so.addVariable("color_path","songs_related/flashmp3player/default.xml"); // Location of xml file with color settings.
    so.addVariable("script_path","songs_related/flashmp3player/flashmp3player.php");     
    // Location of php script.
    so.write("player"); 
</script>
```

This is how i include the player backend

```
<div id="main_music_player_for_the_site">
    <?php include_once('player_codes.php'); ?>
</div>
```

If you go to this link [here](http://bedupako.com/songs.php) and press play on any song in the list the following happens:

1. I send a request to backend and set the song.
2. Confirmation comes to me.
3. I load the player from the player_codes.php (given above)

But when step 3 happens it refreshes! *and gets stuck*

**It should not refersh** its not refreshing in my localhost also.

Here is my JS that does the work (called after i get a response in step 2)

```
function callBackForLoadSong(data)
{
    //alert(data);
    if(data == "failed")
    {
        alert("Song requres you to login. Its easy to create an account! We will take you to the login page after you press ok");
        window.location.replace(REDIRECT);
    }
    else
    {
        //alert("s");
        $("#main_music_player_for_the_site").text("refreshing player...");
        $("#main_music_player_for_the_site").load("player_codes.php");
    }
}
```

*Main thing thats bugging me is why is the page getting refreshed??? and getting stuck*

Comment: Yea, yea, we're all in a hurry. But don't tag your questions "urgent", and spend some more time on spelling and formatting if you want to get decent answers!

Comment: ya the title was a bit misleading. will be careful next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same HREF for every play buttons. Looks like your onClick event loads the songs?

You should have :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadSong('849','http://bedupako.com/songs.php');return false;">play</a>
```

Instead of :

```
<a href="songs_related/create_play_list.php?single=0&amp;songid=849&amp;url=http://bedupako.com/songs.php" onclick="loadSong('849','http://bedupako.com/songs.php');return false;">play</a>
```

Right now, you tell javascript to load your song with the onClick event and you tell the browser to go to a different URL using HREF. javascript:void(0) will prevent the browser to execute the HREF.

Comment: Actually, `return false` already prevents the link being followed. His use of `href` is silly, but ultimately not the problem.

Comment: wow soooo simple :) 1 doubt tho is that i want to have that href there for a fall back when there is no JS. How to do it?

Comment: @Tomalak The solution did work. !!! but i want href also... hmmm may be i will try to replace href in ready() function of jquery with javascript:void(0);

Comment: @footy Why do you need the HREF at this specific moment? 1. You tell javascript to load the song. If you change the URL at the same time, the browser refreshes the page and you start over...

Comment: @footy: Then you must also have had an error in `loadSong` preventing Javascript execution from completing. The two snippets in this answer have _the same effect_.

Answer (score 0):

Well the actual problem lied in my return value of false AFTER I EXECUTE MY CALL BACK!!!

Here is the corrected JS :

```
function callBackForLoadSong(data)
{
    //alert(data);
    if(data == "failed")
    {
        alert("Song requres you to login. Its easy to create an account! We will take you to the login page after you press ok");
        window.location.replace(REDIRECT);
    }
    else
    {
        //alert("s");
        $("#main_music_player_for_the_site").text("refreshing player...");
        $("#main_music_player_for_the_site").load("player_codes.php");
    }
    return false;
}
```

so a return false; must be specified in the function also

Comment: Not likely. But since you didn't ever show the use of this function it's hard to know what you're doing.

Comment: Well if you could go to the link and check it if there was other errors it would be helpful. The function is a call back to the data i send to thir server via this link from another function $.get(to,parm,callBackForLoadSong);

Comment: I don't have time to debug your webpage for you. Please make a complete, minimal testcase for your questions; you do the debugging, we do the explaining!

Comment: Well i dont want you to debug! i can do that myself.Firebug helps me in that :P. always happy that the community helps.